# node.js and apache on different servers

Tags: php, node.js, apache, socket.io, lamp

I have node.js and socket.io on server A and lamp on server B. Server B is the website that runs everything that my sites need except I want server A to take care of the chat feature I have on server B.

I'm kinda new to node.js and socket.io, But got the hang of sending and receiving messages on server A with a simple index.html.

My question is... what's the best way or how do you send and receive messages from server B to A and back? so I can keep everything I already wrote on server B and just use server A to serve as the chat server for all the messages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript on web server A:

```
<script src="http://serverB.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://serverB.com');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

NodeJS server B:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: This seems to work.. but when I open 2 tabs of the same chat app. the messages get sent but not on both tabs. Any idea?

Comment: nvm.. I got it.. io.sockets.emit.