# Linking CSS and images to my EJS templates on remote Express server with Node.js (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs, bad-gateway

I have been extensively searching in here but every solution I tried kept failing, so here's my problem:

I have developed locally a basic Express server to display a static page until I finished my full integration.
My site structure is :

```
/node_modules
/public/
    css/
        styles.css
    images/
        Logo-large.jpg
/views/
    partials/
        footer.ejs
        header.ejs
    contact.ejs
    home.ejs
    signup.ejs
.env
index.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

Here's the result:
[Locally on my Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuuEa.png)

When deployed onto my Ubuntu sever and node started, here's the result remotely:
[Remotely on the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NG27.png)

## index.js

```
//jshint esversion:6

require('dotenv').config();
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const _ = require("lodash");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/contactDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

// <===== DECLARING DATABASE SCHEMA =====>

const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String,
  company: String,
  phone: String,
  email: String
});

// <===== DECLARING DATABASE MODEL =====>

const Contact = new mongoose.model("Contact", contactSchema);

// <===== ROUTES =====>

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("home");
});

app.get("/contact", function(req, res) {
  res.render("contact");
});

app.get("/signup", function(req, res) {
  res.render("signup");
});

let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 3000;
}

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port " + port);
});
```

## styles.css

```
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  margin: 50px auto 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
}

h3 {
  margin: 50px auto 50px;
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
}

#main-logo {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

## header.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Lub + Glass Consulting by Thierry Di Lenarda</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
```

## home.ejs

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>

  <h1>Welcome to Lub + Glass Consulting!<br>We are under construction...</h1>

  <img id="main-logo" src="/images/Logo-large.jpg" alt="Logo TLGC">

  <h3>Come back soon to learn more about the services I can provide.<br><br><em>Thierry Di Lenarda</em></h3>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

## footer.ejs

```
  </body>
  <footer>

  </footer>
</html>
```

contact.ejs and signup.ejs are empty. I want this "home.ejs" page to render properly before getting started with everything else.

Can someone see if/where I did wrong? Every answer that I found in stackoverflow failed until now. Impossible to access or display anything from the 'public' folder.

Thanks for the help!

[EDIT]
I have "GET 502 (Proxy Error)" for the image,
and "GET net::ERR_ABORTED 502 (Proxy Error)" for the css file.

Solved by adding a "/" at the end of the ProxyPass in the Vhost thanks to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375975/502-proxy-error-in-express-js-while-integrating-with-apache)

> ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
>          ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000/

[/EDIT]

Answer (score 0):

- [1](https://www.dilenarda.com/public/images/Logo-large.jpg) This issue is related to your links, check the links.
- [2](https://www.dilenarda.com/public/css/styles.css) Your server is not responding for these links there is some error in accessing to these links due to which your files are not usable. kindly check them.